# How can I calculate the exponential integral?

Tags: floating-point, mathematical-programming

(I'm not sure this is the right forum.)

I'm writing a program that uses the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  Right now, I'm using `x/log(x)`, but I want to switch to something more accurate.  A better approximation is the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) (actually, its Eulerian variant), which can be computed from the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).  Now how can I compute the exponential integral?  I'm on a macOS Intel system using Swift, so I can use the various advanced floating-point functions provided by Apple's system libraries if needed to help.

Comment: You might get a better answer on [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @RobertAndrews, I [re-asked](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/33720/4988) on that exchange.